# Copy values from Dataframe to new Dataframe depending on value in first column and first row

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes. DF1 has in first column dates and in first row company names (several hundreds each).

DF1 looks like:

```
Date        Name1   Name2   Name3
01.01.2014  2       1       2
02.01.2014  3       2       3
03.01.2014  4       3       4
01.02.2014  5       4       5
```

DF2 has the dates and company names in the first two columns and looks like that:

```
Date         Company   
01.01.2014   Name1       
01.01.2014   Name2     
01.01.2014   Name3     
02.01.2014   Name1     
02.01.2014   Name2     
02.01.2014   Name3     
03.01.2014   Name1     
03.01.2014   Name2     
03.01.2014   Name3     
01.02.2014   Name1     
01.02.2014   Name2     
01.02.2014   Name3
```

I want to copy the values of the DF1 into DF2, depending on date and company name.
The new dataframe DF3 should look like this:

```
Date         Company   Value
01.01.2014   Name1     2   
01.01.2014   Name2     1
01.01.2014   Name3     2
02.01.2014   Name1     3
02.01.2014   Name2     2
02.01.2014   Name3     3
03.01.2014   Name1     4
03.01.2014   Name2     3
03.01.2014   Name3     4
01.02.2014   Name1     5
01.02.2014   Name2     4
01.02.2014   Name3     5
```

Edit:
Not sure how this is a duplicate to the linked question, because this is with R, the linked question with Unix, which doesn't help me because I can't translate the Unix code to R due to insufficient R knowledge...

Comment: Are there any dates in `DF2` that you would want to keep and would not be in `DF1`? If there aren't (i.e. `DF1` has everything you want) you could simply melt `DF1`: `df_m<-melt(DF1,id.vars="Date")`

Comment: Works perfectly, even easier solution than I would have thought! Thanks!